# Unable to find iPhone 7, iPhone 7 Plus and lower modal devices in latest Xcode version 11.2.1

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode11

I have updated my Xcode to the latest version (11.2.1). But I not found some of the lower modals in Xcode 11.2.1.

Can anyone clarify what is the reason for that? Screenshot from my Xcode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simulators and devices displayed in this listed depends on the target version.

Select your project, then the desired target, and in the **Deployment info**, lower the Target version :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to create the simulators to represent those devices under `Window -> Devices and Simulators` in Xcode. Xcode now only ships with simulators for devices Apple considers to be the most popular.

[image]